# JMP script to automatically open Images

Tags: sas-jmp

I've a JMP file that contains a lot of information extracted from images. For example:

> "Feature 1" "Feature 2" "Image FullPath"
>
> 1 2.1 "/myimage1path/myimagename1"
>
> 3 4.0 "/myimage2path/myimagename2"

When I analyze the features, I select some images of interest. I would like to **automatically open the selected images**.

To do so, I know that I have to create a JMP script. Can I do one of the following using JMP scripts?

- Start an external program like GIMP/ImageJ and give the full path of all my images?
- Call/launch a Python or Java program. In that case I know how to develop what I need with Python or Java, but I don't know how to call it from JMP script.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Run Program function from the JSL script.

[Run Program Reference](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Utility_Functions.shtml#4547957)